# Can clone VM be application backup plan?

Tags: security, backup, virtualization, clone

I am application developer and don't know much about virtual machine(VM). 
however, our application is resided on a VM. frequent patch need be apply to fix/update this application. For diaster recovery, It was suggest to backup every thing on the server. so, once server is restored, no application need be re-installed and configured.

our network administrator thinks it can be done by cloning VM. but if we want to backup the clone to a tape. it would expose VM to backup drive. any one who can access to it can erase the VM and every thing woudl be gone. it is very risky.

I would appreciate it if you could let me what you think on this or any suggestion.

Comment: "backing up [something] is very risky, because anyone with access to the backups can erase it and everything would be gone". If anyone can erase your backups, you seem to have a HUGE problem with access rights, not with backups.

Answer (score 2):

Cloning is perfectly acceptable.

You don't have to backup to tape... It can be done to a NAS for example, and with the proper security and setup, backups cannot be deleted by unauthorized people.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any NAS and VM replication software like Veeam, Acronis or [Nakivo](https://www.nakivo.com/). It will totally solve your problems. All software has various permission settings so you can control who can and who can not delete your data.